# JointsWP 3 (Foundation 6) Mega Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, zurb-foundation

Ok, this is something that I am sure would come handy to most of WordPress devs using jointsWP as their starter theme. There is no OOTB solution for doing this, and I am afraid I lack the proper knowledge to develop it myself without any advice.

I can see that there already is a mega menu walker for Bootstrap 3 on GitHub that I think could be integrated with foundation. My current question is, do you have any suggestion how to modify this? I thought about using the foundation content dropdown (JS) but there is tons of residual styling since it really wasnt meant to be used in such a way.

https://github.com/macdonaldr93/yamm-nav-walker/